# Output complex xml from SQL select query

Tags: sql-server, xml, select

I am trying to generate XML from a SQL Server select Query. I would like the output to look like this:

```
<Root Version="3.3" UnitsOfMeasure="metric">
<Header>
    <HeaderID CountryCode="TH" LanguageCode="tha" Name="บริษัท เลิศวนิชออยล์ จำกัด สาขา 1" IDType="Local">88</HeaderID>
</Header>
<Item>
    <ItemID Name="Premium Unleaded">4021</ItemID>
    <SubItem>
        <SubItemID Name="T3">3</SubItemID>
        <TimeStamp>
            <Date>2015-09-19</Date>
            <Time>14:09</Time>
        </TimeStamp>
    </SubItem>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ItemID Name="Diesel">4041</ItemID>
    <SubItem>
        <SubItemID Name="T1">1</SubItemID>
        <TimeStamp>
            <Date>2015-09-19</Date>
            <Time>14:09</Time>
        </TimeStamp>
    </SubItem>
    <SubItem>
        <SubItemID Name="T7">7</SubItemID>
        <TimeStamp>
            <Date>2015-09-19</Date>
            <Time>14:09</Time>
        </TimeStamp>
    </SubItem>
</Item>
</Root>
```

The database structure is

- `HeaderTable` joins to `ItemTable` via `HeaderID` foreign key
- `ItemTable` joins to `SubItemTable` via `HeaderID` and `ItemID` as the primary key

Let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I've done this quite successfully using the FOR XML command.  The documentation is pretty good too.

Comment: where could I find the documentation?

Comment: The Microsoft documentation is a solid place to start on this one, try here; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms178107.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the following example XML Generation from SQL Query...

```
SELECT e.EmployeeID AS "@EmpID",
   c.FirstName AS "EmployeeName/FirstName",
   c.MiddleName AS "EmployeeName/MiddleName",
   c.EmailAddress,
   c.LastName AS "EmployeeName/LastName"
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS e
   INNER JOIN Person.Contact AS c
   ON c.ContactID = e.ContactID
WHERE c.FirstName = 'Rob'
FOR XML PATH ('Employee'), ROOT ('Employees'), ELEMENTS XSINIL;
```

Generated XML is as follows...similarly change your code accordingly.. :-

```
<Employees xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Employee EmpID="4">
    <EmployeeName>
      <FirstName>Rob</FirstName>
      <MiddleName xsi:nil="true" />
    </EmployeeName>
    <EmailAddress>rob0@adventure-works.com</EmailAddress>
    <EmployeeName>
      <LastName>Walters</LastName>
    </EmployeeName>
  </Employee>
  <Employee EmpID="168">
    <EmployeeName>
      <FirstName>Rob</FirstName>
      <MiddleName>T</MiddleName>
    </EmployeeName>
    <EmailAddress>rob1@adventure-works.com</EmailAddress>
    <EmployeeName>
      <LastName>Caron</LastName>
    </EmployeeName>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Comment: @TobyJackson Refer the above code and let me know whether it worked or not !!! I hope the latest updated post answers your requirement.